# Mac Finder log/history: Is there a way to see more details of undo/redo states/actions?

Tags: mac, file-management, finder

Occasionally, I will accidentally undo more than I wanted to while working in Finder. Yet for some reason, the "redo" option isn't available. So if a number of files were moved/deleted/etc., I have no way of knowing what I just undid.

Is there a log somewhere that would allow me to see details of the actions performed in Finder? I've tried looking in the Console app at the system log, but that doesn't seem to contain this info. I'm not sure what else to check.

Also, is there a similar log for file actions performed by Terminal commands?

In case it makes a difference on how I can find this info, I have one MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9 Mavericks, and another running MacOS Sierra 10.12.

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to pinpoint Finder-specific changes, but a starting point might be "Path Finder" (a third-party app) or something similar that can perform a manual search of all files.  This is what I've used for recovering files from my *entire* computer. App alternatives *might* include "Double Commander", "Thunar", "Commander One", "Forklift", but I can't verify their functionality in this scenario.

Otherwise, the default (and most basic/insufficient) answer I've found on the Web to scour your computer's files is using *search criteria in a Finder search* for all recently modified files/folders, though this doesn't seem to include Trash'ed items.

Here is the basic approach:

[image: search criteria panel]

1. Open Finder
2. Click search box or press `⌘`+F (Do not type anything in there!)

   *(the search criteria panel should appear, as shown above)*
3. Apply settings:

   - `Search:` "This Mac"
   - `Last modified date:` "today" *(or other timeframe)*
4. Use "Date Modified" column to sort...

   - *Add "Date Modified" column to your Finder window:* `ctrl`+click on any column header to open submenu with column types
   - Sort "Date Modified" column by ascending or descending order by clicking on that column's header

***NOTE:** I'm not sure how system files are presented with these settings, but you can create another search filtering system files separately to see what shows up.*

#### A step further

You can then save this as Smart Folder so you don't have to enter the settings again.